# Infinitive vs Gerund Usage differences

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund, to-infinitive

> 1). I have no choice but **to run away**.
>
> 2). I have no choice but **running away**.

Which one is correct and Why ?  If both are correct, What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Comment: It seems this question has been [asked many times](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=infinitive+gerund).

Comment: They are both correct and have the same meaning.

Comment: @ramteja There's no difference in meaning. The only difference is the latter is less common.

Comment: I'd say that 2) is ungrammatical since "choice" does not licence (permit) a gerund-participial (_ing_) clause as complement.

Answer (score 0):

It is a sentence with the coordinating conjuction *but*, where an independent clause "I have no choice" may join either the phrase *to run away* or *running away*.

Because the object in the independent clause is *choice* that is a noun and the conjunction "but" is a coordinating one, we should use a phrase functioning as a noun after *but*.

It may seem that both phrases, *to run away* and *running away*, could function as a noun in such a sentence in the first sight.

But, there is a semantical limitation for constructing the sentence only on the grounds mentioned. To test options, we ought to substitute the OP sentence with the sentence *I have the choice+the independent phrase*.

In case of *running away*, it functions as a relative participle phrase that modifies the subject personal pronoun "I" in the test sentence.

This test can show that *to run away* is the only possible option.